# Preventing device wake up on USB

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, power-on, usb-host-mode

Is there a way of preventing an Android device from waking up/staying awake when a USB is device is plugged in?

I know Windows allows this in device manager. Is there a similar setting in Android or can I accomplish this via changing configuration over ADB/fastboot?

Actually, I'm using the LAVA SimulCharge adapter to connect power and a USB device. When the power is lost, I dont want android to stay awake.

**UPDATE**

Video to explain the issue
https://goo.gl/photos/FQxKmDRWKqxbwgPb6

- Screen timeout set to 5 seconds to demonstrate.
- Screen lock set to none (but same with swipe or PIN. Just will show the lock screen instead)
- Pressing the power button turns off the screen momentarily, but wakes up almost immediately.
- *Sometimes* After about 5 minutes of this, the EasyCAP light stops blinking and the screen turns off, but the device battery level drops about 10% per hour while its *"asleep"* unless the OTG adapter is removed.
- Removing the power cable from the OTG adapter end (instead of the wall end as I did in the video) lets the tablet sleep properly.

Comment: Try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) : *Trigger:* Power disconnected *Action:* Screen off *Constraints:* leave blank

Comment: Actually the screen is off.. but the baterry drains, unless I disconnect the adapter.

Comment: If your device is rooted, you can use *reboot/ power off* as action instead of *screen off*

Comment: yea. I'm considering that now. It seems like the popular `plm` file trick works only for Samsung devices. I'm looking for a universal solution. I also need to power on on charger as well.. Which is time consuming and also, the surefire support for that type of thing also seem like just samsung devices.

Comment: Well, if this automation works for you, let me know to post an answer, but gut feeling is that it would do a part of the overall task you are trying to achieve - which is quite ambitious, simply because the *devil lies in details* and there can be any number of variations in actual production rendering inter workability suspect

Comment: Actually automate didn't work. It did engage the lock screen, but the screen keeps waking up continuously. (I will update the question with a video link. I have set the screen timeout to 5 seconds to demonstrate)

Comment: Yes, like i said in my earlier comment, i expected it to do a " part" only, though initially it seemed workable,.

Comment: Does anyone found a solution? I have related problem and posted as a short question here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214620/how-to-wake-up-my-android-device-via-wireless-keyboard-mouse-it-has-dongle-con  @beeshyams