# disabling USB via init.usb.rc

Tags: root-access, usb, usb-connection-mode, usb-on-the-go

I have a tablet and a LAVA SimulCharge adapter.

I would like to disconnect all USB devices when power is disconnected and reconnect them when power is connected.

Is this possible to do via changes to `init.usb.rc` ?

(My device is Galaxy Tab S2 LTE android 6.0.1 rooted via SuperSU systemless root.)

I'm thinking something like

`on property:sys.usb.config=*accessory?*
    write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable 0`

`on property:sys.usb.config=*charging?* # or is it charging,accessory ?
    write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable 1`

Reason is that when the charger is disconnected from the LAVA adapter, this [prevents the tablet from sleeping](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/156270/preventing-device-wake-up-on-usb) and drains baterry.

Comment: Try [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/106232). If that works out would be possible to automate

Comment: sorry.. tried `echo 0 > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable` and didn't work. ES File Explorer shows that this file has value 0, yet the USB is device is still connected and wakes up the tablet.